# How to stop a function from being called when the page opens

Tags: javascript

So I have this Sweetalert2 function and it works great. Except it runs as soon as the page loads which is not what I want.

What I want is when I click on an element. I want it to be executed!

Also, I noticed that if the alert runs for the first time. It doesn't run when I click it because it ran on the first time

HTML

```
 <i class="fas fa-search navigation__search-cart--icon"></i>
```

JS (SweetAlert file. From here I'm exporting the function that always gets called.)

```
export default sweetAlert = Swal.fire({
  title: "Search...",
  input: "text",
  inputAttributes: {
    autocapitalize: "off"
  },
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: "Search",
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: async val => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`//api.github.com/users/${val}`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response.json();
    } catch (err) {
      Swal.showValidationMessage(`Request failed: ${err}`);
    }
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
}).then(result => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: `${result.value.login}'s avatar`,
      imageUrl: result.value.avatar_url
    });
  }
});
```

JS (Where the actual click happens)

```
import sweetAlert from "./sweetAlert";

const search = document.querySelector(
  ".fas.fa-search.navigation__search-cart--icon"
);

search.addEventListener("click", sweetAlert);
```

What should I do to stop the function from running on page load? And how can I make it run whenever I click on the element?

Comment: Your example is from: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#methods -- AJAX request example. It doesn't automatically popup. What version of `sweetalert` are you using?

Comment: sweet alert 2...

Comment: After following the sweetalert example's codepen I realized you need to wrap your fire somehow. Here is a working sample: https://codepen.io/neil-lindberg/pen/povvJBX

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I found a new way!